# How can I implement the Connection Weight Product model interpretability method in Python?

Tags: python, r, keras, interpretation

I want to interpret my Keras Tensorflow model using [Olden's Connection Weight Product method](https://rdrr.io/cran/NeuralNetTools/man/olden.html)

I know there is a Package available for it in R but is there a way to implement this method natively in Python?

Thank you so much!

Alternatively, how would I go about interpreting it in R?

Would I just export it as a H5 file and then use the R package?